# How do I display more data separately?

Tags: android, bluetooth

```
   **bluetoothdatadisplay**
 void beginListenForData() {
                //final Handler handler = new Handler();
                final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                final byte delimiter = 10; //This is the ASCII code for a newline character

                stopWorker = false;
                readBufferPosition = 0;
                readBuffer = new byte[2048];//It uses a 1024 bytes long buffer because it doesn't have any way of knowing the length of the input stream.
                workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker) {
                            try {
                                int bytesAvailable = mmInputStream.available();
                                if (bytesAvailable > 0) {
                                    byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                                    mmInputStream.read(packetBytes);
                                    for (int i = 0; i < bytesAvailable; i++) {
                                        byte b = packetBytes[i];
                                        if (b == delimiter) {
                                            byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                                            System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
                                            final String data = new String(encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
                                            readBufferPosition = 0;

                                            handler.post(new Runnable() {

                                                public void run() {

                                                    myLabel.setText(data);
                                                    //Log.d("MyLabel", data);
                                                }
                                            });

                                        } else {
                                            readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            } catch (IOException ex) {
                                stopWorker = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

                workerThread.start();
            }//end of begindata
```

Hi I trying to receive the data from Arduino, But when I send all my data were flashing very fast since there is only one textview use. How do I separate them in Android for eg into different textbox? Thanks!

Comment: Instead of adding complete code, only paste the code that is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`RecyclerView`](http://[1]), with a `List<String>` representing your data set and connected to the `Adapter` of the `RecyclerView` :-) 
Each time you add something to the data list, use

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

method to have the RecyclerView update :-)

EDIT:

As stated by **Kernald**, you should actually use the

```
adapter.notifyItemInserted(list.size())
```

method instead of notifying the whole data set change, if you want to use a 100% correct and up-to-time approach :-)

Comment: `notifyDataSetChanged()` should not be used for simple updates like that.

Comment: And why exactly? The View will only redraw the visible, changed views. This is exactly the situation this method should be called in :-) Well, it is true that for RecyclerView one of the NotifyInserted/Removed methods could and should be called, but the OP is clearly new to Android and I did not want to confuse them, as notifyDataSetChanged method is ok as well, it just won't play an animation :-)

Comment: It won't play an animation, and more than redrawing the visible, changed views, the recycler view will have to query again all those visible items from the adapter. It's not simpler in this case, and it's less efficient, so just calling `notifyItemInserted(list.size())` would be a better solution in my opinion :-)

Comment: It will, but it will not recreate the Views, just rebind them. But you are 100% right, the RecyclerView-specific method should rather be used here, I just did not want to confuse the OP :-)

Comment: Sure. But keep in mind that the OP is not the only person who will read this answer ;-)

Comment: Thanks! I will give your suggestions a try. Yea very new to Android. :( Will update you guys again! :)

Comment: @Kernald I tried using recycleviewer but I getting null error. :( I think I do it wrongly. below is my code. I upload to dropbox https://www.dropbox.com/s/h4uahwun5kka3wc/bluetooth_datadisplay.txt?dl=0

Comment: recycle adapter code https://www.dropbox.com/s/jq9fcw2s0ebwdxh/recycleadapter.txt?dl=0

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7f1324rfrj1fu29/errror.txt?dl=0 error link. And I followed this link tutorial http://techlovejump.com/android-recyclerview-to-create-list-like-view/ Hi @Kelevandos help please. I not sure how to use a list<string> to represent data?

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix would be to [append](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#append%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) the newly received data instead of replacing the old one.

Comment: I doubt this will give the expected result in situation where the "data were flashing very fast" - the TextView will quickly exceed the height of the screen and the further data will be illegible